# addEventListener doesn't work with default paramaters

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why do functions with default parameters not work if i call the function with `addEventListener`?

This example function below generates some random strings, and i called the function by using `onclick()` in the html file, which perfectly works

```js
const notationGraph = {
  "U": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "D": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "L": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "R": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "F": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
  "B": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
};

const switches = ["", "\'", "2"]; 

function randItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function generate3x3(Min = 20, Max = 25) {
  let scrambles = []; 
  let prev;
  const len = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
    let notation = randItem(prev ? notationGraph[prev] : Object.keys(notationGraph));
    let swtch = randItem(switches);
    scrambles.push(`${notation}${swtch}`);
    prev = notation;
  }
  console.log(scrambles.join(" "));
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonTest" onclick="generate3x3()">test button</button>
```

But with the `addEventListener` method, it does not work and `console.log`s empty strings

```js
const notationGraph = {
  "U": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "D": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "L": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "R": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "F": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
  "B": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
};

const switches = ["", "\'", "2"]; 

function randItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function generate3x3(Min = 20, Max = 25) {
  let scrambles = []; 
  let prev;
  const len = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
    let notation = randItem(prev ? notationGraph[prev] : Object.keys(notationGraph));
    let swtch = randItem(switches);
    scrambles.push(`${notation}${swtch}`);
    prev = notation;
  }
  console.log(scrambles.join(" "));
}
document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click", generate3x3)
```

```html
<button id="buttonTest">test button</button>
```

I'm wondering why doesn't it work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you forgot to use braces. 
document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click", generate3x3())

Comment: @M.HassanNasir No, that is incorrect. Then the function is executed at the bind time, not the event time. For your suggestion to work, the function would have to return a function

Comment: document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click", function(){generate3x3()}).
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @M.HassanNasir Yes, as I have answered

Comment: e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the event passed in the eventListener is overwriting your first default parameter

EITHER add the event to the function as the first parameter

```
function generate3x3(event, Min = 20, Max = 25) {
```

OR call it like this

```
document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click",function() {
  generate3x3();
})
```

```js
const notationGraph = {
  "U": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "D": ["L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "L": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "R": ["U", "D", "F", "B"],
  "F": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
  "B": ["U", "D", "L", "R"],
};

const switches = ["", "\'", "2"]; 

function randItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function generate3x3(Min = 20, Max = 25) {
  let scrambles = []; 
  let prev;
  const len = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
    let notation = randItem(prev ? notationGraph[prev] : Object.keys(notationGraph));
    let swtch = randItem(switches);
    scrambles.push(`${notation}${swtch}`);
    prev = notation;
  }
  console.log(scrambles.join(" "));
}

document.getElementById("buttonTest").addEventListener("click",function() {
  generate3x3()
})
```

```html
<button id="buttonTest">test button</button>
```

Comment: thanks for answering :D, does this mean i have to put the function in a function like that whenever im trying to run a function that has parameters?

Comment: See update. You can add the event as a first parameter

Comment: You are welcome. I have not used default parameters so I had to think for a bit too.